# Run a python file which uses a Unicode character in the filename from a batch file

Tags: python, batch-file, utf-8, anaconda, streamlit

Pretty simple bat file I am trying to run that essentially changes a directory/environment and then uses streamlit to run a program but I cannot for the life of me get it to recognize the unicode character being used. Here is the .bat file

```
@echo off
chcp 65001
call "C:\...\Miniconda3\Scripts\activate.bat"
call conda activate env
cd C:\...\Documents\GitHub\...
streamlit run _Project.py
pause
```

I haven't had issues until somewhat recently but no matter what when I run this bat file (or run line by line in anaconda prompt) I get an error with the unicode reading incorrectly on the globe unicode character.

```
Error: Invalid value: File does not exist: ??_Project.py
```

I can't change the name of the file as it is in a larger repository. I have tried saving the bat file under multiple different formats (UTF-8 I believe should be correct) and I have tried tweaking fonts to see if there is something weird with that but haven't had any luck. Is there any work around aside from manually renaming the file and everywhere it appears on my local?

Comment: Looks like `streamlit` might be the problem here, the error indicates two characters where there should only be one.

Comment: @MarkRansom - That's just how Unicode works. Pretty much all characters are going to be a combination of multiple bytes.

Comment: I will agree, however, that if you've saved the script as UTF-8 and you've got the `chcp 65001` command in there, then the issue is most likely with `streamlit`. You can confirm this by trying to run `type _Project.py`. If there's a problem with the batch script, you'll get the error `The system cannot find the file specified.` and if everything is working you'll see the text of the python file.

Comment: if I update to type _Project.py it will display the contents of the file so perhaps it is an issue with streamlit specifically when evoked via command window (program runs fine when deployed just using a local version where I run into issues)

Comment: `FOR %%b IN ("_Project.py") DO streamlit "%%b" …` perhaps? Or perhaps you could use the short filename if that is being generated by your system (dir /x "_Project.py")

Answer (score -1):

The issue you are facing seems to be related to CMD's limited suport for Unicode characters. Even after changing the code page using `chcp 65001` to enable UTF-8 encoding, CMD may not fully support Unicode characters like the globe emoji "" in the file name. That being said, it really varies on your needs to find the best solution.

In my situation, the command seems to function as expected. This could potentially be attributed to the fact that I'm using Windows 10, which is a more updated OS, although I can't say for certain. Occasionally, the use of quotation marks is necessary, but otherwise, it operates without issues, which may indicate you are saving the file with incorrect original encoding. Even though, below I present some solutions.

### Using Short Filename (8.3 Filename)

This solution is best if you want to keep your code in pure batch.

1. Navigate to the directory where your Python script is located in
   Command Prompt.
2. Run `dir /x` to see the short 8.3 filenames alongside the regular
   filenames.
3. Identify the short filename for _Project.py.
4. Use the short filename in your .bat script instead of _Project.py.

For example, if the short filename is GLOBE~1.PY, then modify your .bat script like this:

```
@echo off
chcp 65001
call "C:\...\Miniconda3\Scripts\activate.bat"
call conda activate env
cd C:\...\Documents\GitHub\...
streamlit run GLOBE~1.PY
pause
```

Windows has this function, and it's very useful for your purpose.

### Using PowerShell

You can replace the entire batch file with a PowerShell script, which has much better support for Unicode and other features, which you may want to add on later.

Create a `.ps1` file with the following content:

```
$env:Path += ";C:\...\Miniconda3\Scripts\"
conda activate env
Set-Location "C:\...\Documents\GitHub\..."
streamlit run "_Project.py"
pause
```

To run the PowerShell script, right-click it and select "Run with PowerShell".

This way, you can have a more flexible environment and the guarantee of it working.

### Manual Renaming (If no other option)

If the above solutions are not suitable, and you can't change the original filename, you could copy the file to a temporary one with an ASCII name, run it, and then delete it. This is not the most elegant solution, but will work, if the case is you can't run but can access it.

```
@echo off
chcp 65001
call "C:\...\Miniconda3\Scripts\activate.bat"
call conda activate env
cd C:\...\Documents\GitHub\...
copy "_Project.py" "temp_Project.py"
streamlit run temp_Project.py
del "temp_Project.py"
pause
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: When you say, "I'm using Windows 10, which is a more updated OS," what do you mean by that? More updated than what?

Comment: By stating that I am using Windows 10, I aim to highlight that it is a more current operating system in comparison to older versions such as Windows 7 and below. My implication is that the author of the post may be operating on an outdated platform where certain functionalities, like Unicode support in the command prompt, may not yet be available, as it worked perfectly fine in my command prompt, even though I gave an appropriate fix. @GeneralGrievance